# javascript filebrowser window

Tags: asp.net

I have a javascript function which store the values in cookies and open another page (addfile.aspx) using window.open. Addfile.aspx page contain button, onclicking it prompt file browser window. My requirement is  if the file the user selected is zero kb then it doesn't allow to added to the grid in addfile.aspx page and show a message that inform the user the file cannot be zero byte. How I can do it ? While user select a file from file browser window, I save the file name and file path to variables using a javascript function. How I can Get the file size... Is there any method in javascript to extract the file size....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible using Javascript, but you can check the size of the file using `FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength` property.

More info [FileUpload.PostedFile Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx)

Comment: no I am using a HTMl file control instead of fileuploader. On click event of that control i called javaascript function which store the file browser widow. as follows